# Stripe Webhook PHP - Subscription Cancelation Event

Tags: php, stripe-payments

New to Stripe and building a simple webhook to capture subscription details and provision access to a website.

Following https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=checkout

Questions:

Does `invoice.payment_failed` capture subscription cancellations? Say a customer logs into the portal and cancels their subscription for expiry at end of the subscription period, does `invoice.payment_failed` get automatically triggered at end of the subscription period? Or do I need to also listen for something else?

I am also listening for `invoice.paid` and `invoice.payment_failed` events, is it also correct to retrieve details via the Session object? I am currently using the Session object for `invoice.paid` events and saving customer / subscription details:

```
    $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve([
        'id' => $event->data->object->id,
        ['expand' => ['customer', 'subscription']] // Multiple expand
    ]);

    $customer_email = $session->customer->email;
    $session_id = $session->id; 
    etc etc
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You'll receive a `customer.subscription.deleted` event when the subscription ends. Visit this [page](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks) to see the list of webhook events related to subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you. Can I retrieve the customer's details thru a Session object?

Comment: If a customer is created by the checkout (depends on https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer_creation) Then yes you can expect to get a customer from the checkout session ( https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer)

Comment: Sorry I meant in this particular case. If a customer.subscription.deleted event occurs, does a session object get created? The documentation mentions successful checkouts, what about cancellations?

Comment: No, no checkout session is created when a subscription ends.